# Socket.recv() в бесконечном цикле перестает работать после нескольких итераций

Tags: python-3.x, twitch

Я студент, который только начинает изучать Python, но я уже знаю основы CS. Я столкнулся с проблемой, когда пытался написать простого бота для Твича. Мой код выглядит так:

```
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((config.HOST, config.PORT))
s.send("PASS {}\r\n".format(config.PASS).encode())
s.send("NICK {}\r\n".format(config.NICK).encode())
s.send("JOIN {}\r\n".format(config.CHANNEL).encode())

chat_message = re.compile(r"^:\w+!\w+@\w+\.tmi\.twitch\.tv PRIVMSG #\w+ :")

mes(s, "Twitch bot connected to chat!")

#_thread.start_new_thread(getmoderators(), ())
while True:
    response = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    if response == "PING :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n":
        s.send("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n".encode("utf-8"))
    else:
        username = re.search(r"\w+", response).group(0)
        message = chat_message.sub("", response)
        print(response)
```

Но цикл срабатывает в несколько итераций и доходит до вот такой строки:

```
:CHANNELNAME.tmi.twitch.tv 366 CHANNELNAME CHANNELNAME :End of /NAMES list
```

На этом месте программа подвисает, сообщения не получаются. Никаких ошибок, ничего.

Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Вся суть в том, что Twitch в ответ на мое сообщение о JOIN засылал меня не отображавшимися сообщениями с ошибкой 421 - ошибка в присоединении к каналу. 
Вся проблема была в том, что был передан не верный параметр названия канала. Для исправления такой